# Android SDK. audioManager. setStreamVolume max int value

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-audiomanager

I'm in the process of developing an Android app.

I have been able to successfully set the speaker volume using:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (Audiomanager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, sb2value, 0);
```

The question is, what's the max int value that "sb2value" can be?

FYI, "sb2value" is a value from a slider. As the user slides, the audio volume is changed.

I allow that slider value to go from 0 - 100. Can 100 be used as the second argument value or is the limit lower, such as 20?

Thanks,

P.S. Most of my questions look the same because I'm new, understand that each question needs a new post, and I have a lot of problems for a simple program.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To get the max volume you could set sb2value:

```
sb2value = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

Comment: This is what I've done. I want the volume to have the ability to be varied between 0 and 100. I kept my sb2value variable. I create a second variable and get the max allowable volume integer using your function, divide it by 100 (my desired max value), and then multiple it by the current value at which sb2value is at. This allows me to vary virtually any phone's volume from min to max with increments in between.

Comment: But, I cannot remember if INT's can hold decimal numbers.

Comment: Casting, from C++... sb2value is already an int. I meant the resulting answer could end up as a decimal. if sb2value = 100, 10 (StreamMax) / 100 = 0.1. It's fine, though.

Comment: int's cannot hold decimal values but you could cast it. (int)((sb2value/100) * sb2value). Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [getStreamMaxVolume(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#getStreamMaxVolume%28int%29) method to get the value you need. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of hard coding the max value of your slider (or SeekBar if you are using that), set the Max attribute to `audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(audioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)` This will work better because different devices may have different volume limits.

As far as the actual limit, I'd imagine it isn't above 10.